# eli5 swing worker and swing thread

Tags: java, swing

I had a program I got some help from here([how do I make my program check the stock market value every hour[java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208471/how-do-i-make-my-program-check-the-stock-market-value-every-hourjava/20210351?noredirect=1#20210351)) and I have been reading about swing worker ever since. I still have not fixed the program as I reread the official doc like 3 times and I am still a bit confused. Here is what I think I understand and please correct me if I am wrong.

You use SwingWorker when you have a long background process, and you put the SwingWorker inside your action performed? Once you create your process if you want it to update the GUI you make it return a value and you get() the value from the SwingWorker done() method. I am confused "where" to initialize SwingWorker because I want to say its the action performed, but isn't that where SwingInvokeLater is involved? if that is the case than what is the difference between the two. I believe SwingInvokeLater and done() both update your GUI by being run on the EDT.

I feel lost just writing that all out, I feel like I am getting closer to understanding but for some reason it just wont click. I don't like the examples the official doc provides, I guess I just don't see the whole picture. The official doc said to initialize your GUI inside a SwingInvokeLater but I don't understand the difference between that and just initializing my GUI in main().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions / my replies:

> You use SwingWorker when you have a long background process, and you put the SwingWorker inside your action performed?

It can go inside of an ActionListener, yes. You create it and execute it where it is needed, no more, and no less.

> Once you create your process if you want it to update the GUI you make it return a value and you get() the value from the SwingWorker done() method.

That's one way to update the GUI. You can also use the publish/process method pair to update the GUI with interim results. You can also use a PropertyChangeListener attached to a SwingWorker to update the GUI. No matter what, it's usually a good idea to call `get()` somewhere, even if nothing is returned, as this will allow your Swing GUI to become aware of any exceptions that might have been thrown during the running of your SwingWorker.

> I am confused "where" to initialize SwingWorker because I want to say its the action performed, but isn't that where SwingInvokeLater is involved?

The `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` is used to queue code onto the Swing event thread, the EDT. This is not necessary inside of an ActionListener because its code is already called on the Swing event thread.

> if that is the case than what is the difference between the two.

They are completely different. Again, `invokeLater(...)` is to call code on the event thread, and a SwingWorker is for calling long-running code off of the event thread.

> I believe SwingInvokeLater and done() both update your GUI by being run on the EDT.

Yes they both can.

> The official doc said to initialize your GUI inside a SwingInvokeLater but I don't understand the difference between that and just initializing my GUI in main().

By using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` you guarantee that the code passed into it is run on the EDT, the Event Dispatch Thread. If you don't do this, you don't have this guarantee. While many Swing programs will run most of the time without doing this, they may (and do) sometimes fail if this care isn't taken.

---

**Edit**

> So I guess I am heading in the right direction. If I have a process that checks a value every hour on a website, since its a short process(takes a second) will it be better to use invokeLater()?

You could use some type of timer for this, possibly a ScheduledExecutorService which would be run in the background of Swing, perhaps with a SwingWorker. Then the process would be called background to the Swing thread, and you can update the GUI via publish/process.

> Does the entire block of code go inside invokeLater or just the updating the GUI part. I feel like the entire code should go inside invokeLater but someone told me just to update the GUI such as (text.setText()) inside invokeLater().

As mentioned, your GUI needs to start up inside of a Runnable that is passed into a call to `invokeLater(...)`. As for while your program is running, if the background code is run using a SwingWorker then usually there is no need a call to `invokeLater(...)`. That is one of the reasons for using a SwingWorker rather than a plain vanilla Thread.

---

**Edit 2**
You state:

> one last question I just came across while testing..inside an action performed I made the buttonclick change textfield to say hi, then I put in a try catch for Thread.sleep(1000) then change textfield to say ho. How come the result only outputs ho? it doesnt show hi, I tested with numbers and can see the program locking up. I know using a thread will fix this but just wondering why it wont display the output if I put a sleep.

When you call `Thread.sleep(...)` you put the calling thread, here the Swing Event Dispatch Thread or EDT, to sleep. Since it is responsible for all Swing painting and user interaction, the whole application goes to sleep, and the GUI is unable to perform any updates until the sleep has completed. This is precisely why you must use a background thread to perform this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped a LOT. So I guess I am heading in the right direction. If I have a process that checks a value every hour on a website, since its a short process(takes a second) will it be better to use invokeLater()? Does the entire block of code go inside invokeLater or just the updating the GUI part. I feel like the entire code should go inside invokeLater but someone told me just to update the GUI such as (text.setText()) inside invokeLater().

Comment: one last question I just came across while testing..inside an action performed I made the buttonclick change textfield to say hi, then I put in a try catch for Thread.sleep(1000) then change textfield to say ho. How come the result only outputs ho? it doesnt show hi, I tested with numbers and can see the program locking up. I know using a thread will fix this but just wondering why it wont display the output if I put a sleep.

Comment: @droidbehavior: please see **Edit 2** to answer.